# Date format substitution in PL/SQL. Example: from 5y 6m 20d to 050620

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I am writing a query where I need to perform a date format transformation to meet the specified requirements.

In the database which I have to search, the date format looks like the one in the example: 5y 6m 10d with spaces in between and with optional digits (10y 30d; 1m 23d; 6m are also valid) and they are always ordered (first years, then month and then days).

The format transformation should be the following:

- 10y 6m 10d => 100610
- 1y 10m 1d => 011001
- 6m 2d => 000602

So that the output is always a 6-digit number.

I tried writing regular expressions within REGEX_SUBSTR to isolate the tokens and then concatenate them together in the type of `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_source, '(\d+)*y') FROM database` and I also tried using the `REGEX_REPLACE` function. Nevertheless, I am not able to perform the transformation to two digits per token without spaces, nor replace one pattern by another, I can only replace the pattern by another string.

Although I am able to output the token separation without spaces by writing the function above. I am not able to get the whole transformation. Is there any possibility of writing a RegEx and combining it with any of the PL/SQL functions in order to transform the dates stated on the list above ? I am also open to hear any other solutions not involving RegEx, I just thought it was sensible to make a proper use of them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution in SQL.

- you get the values for year, month and day e.g. with `regexp_substr`.
- with `nvl` you set the value to `0` if there it is null.
- lpad it with 0

```
with tab as(
  select '10y 6m 10d' as str from dual union all
  select '1y 10m 1d ' as str from dual union all
  select '6m 2d ' as str from dual 

)
select lpad(nvl(y,0), 2,'0') ||lpad(nvl(m,0), 2,'0')|| lpad(nvl(d,0), 2,'0')
  from (
     select rtrim(regexp_substr(str, '[0-9]{1,2}y', 1),'y')  as y
           ,rtrim(regexp_substr(str, '[0-9]{1,2}m', 1),'m')  as m
           ,rtrim(regexp_substr(str, '[0-9]{1,2}d', 1),'d')  as d
      from tab
     )
;

LPAD(N
------
100610
011001
000602
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works

```
declare
  myDate_ varchar2(50) := REPLACE('1y 10m 81d',' ','');
  year_ varchar2(50);
  month_ varchar2(50);
  day_ varchar2(50);
begin
       if instrb(myDate_,'y',1,1)>0 then
          year_ := lpad(regexp_substr(substr(myDate_,0,instrb(myDate_,'y',1,1)), '[^y]+',1 , 1),2,0);
       end if;
       if instrb(myDate_,'m',1,1)>0 then
          month_ := lpad(regexp_substr(substr(myDate_,instrb(myDate_,'y',1,1)+1,instrb(myDate_,'m',1,1)), '[^m]+',1 , 1),2,0);
       end if;
        if instrb(myDate_,'d',1,1)>0 then
          day_ := lpad(regexp_substr(substr(myDate_,instrb(myDate_,'m',1,1)+1,instrb(myDate_,'d',1,1)), '[^d]+',1 , 1),2,0);
       end if;
       dbms_output.put_line(year_||month_||day_);
end;
```

Comment: your solution doesn't work e.g. for strings `6m 2d` or `10y 2d`

Comment: why do you need `regexp_substr` and `substr`? you can to do it with  one `substr`